# Python string formatting to control the string's size?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am a Python beginner working on a uni-project that displays the elements of the periodic table, in a neat way.

I know Python's string formatting allows for users to space out strings horizontally, but can I use it to space strings vertically and minimize their font size?

Comment: the font is set by the IDE/cmd you are using

Comment: If you need control over the font, you may want to write html, docbook, LaTeX, or Markdown.